# Non-statically-sized array on stack

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I want to create an array on the stack that varies in size at runtime.  As far as I know, this is always illegal in c++:

```
void local_array(unsigned int i) {
    int arr[i];
}
```

However, it is possible to dynamically allocate memory on the stack using recursion.  Is there a different way to accomplish this without using recursion?  If not, what are the technical limitations preventing the example above from being realized?

Comment: @Blacktempel std::vector allocates memory on the heap.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do and I am not sure you know it either. In B you always have an array of 1 element in the stack unless it is not in the stack (arr != null).

Comment: Without an implementation extension like gcc has (which supports VLA's like you apparently want) you're not going to get this in runtime support out of a standard-only compliant implementation. At least not right now. (and B is nothing even close to a contiguous array).

Comment: @user270349 I'm not sure what you mean here.  The function is called recursively, and every time it's called it adds an integer on the stack.  That adds up to an array of integers.  An int pointer can point to things on the stack - in this case it points to the integer pushed on the first call to local_array_recursive.  Once i is 0, the array has been fully constructed and can be read and written to like any other array.

Comment: I don't believe you have any guarantee about the bits of that array being contiguous.

Comment: @NmdMystery What to you think is also on the stack *between* all those local `int` variables? Nothing? Think again. It is entirely conceivable (and *highly likely* to the point of being near-guaranteed on most platforms) the activation record for the function calls are also on the stack. That said, what you want, [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray/dynarray), isn't available until C++14.

Comment: @NmdMystery Each time it's called it adds other things to the stack, the return address at least and probably other things too. You end up with an array of a lot more than just ints

Comment: @WhozCraig Then lets say I skip the other data.

Comment: @NmdMystery No! You have a lot of sparse int variables (or int[1] arrays).

Comment: @user270349 You can still access all of them, even if they're sparse, provided you can predict the amount of memory each call takes.  See my edit for that.  It has nothing to do with the question I'm asking, though, the code I put together was just a hack to exemplify the problem.

Comment: If it is not contiguous then it is not an array, there are a lot dynamic list structures. You can build a linked list in stack with a recursive function, for example, right, but your question was about arrays.

Comment: @user270349 Pretend I didn't even post B.  The question is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no technical limitation.

You can do this in C++14, and it's already implemented in clang & gcc lastest version.

```
void test(int n)
{
   int a[n]; //ok now
   cout << a[0] << endl; //output a random value on stack!
}
```

Comment: What was the reasoning for it being accepted so late, though?

Comment: Apart from the undefined behavior of indeterminate data evaluation (which is acknowledged in-comment), this is correct.

Comment: @NmdMystery The reason is that, C++ got vector and there's no reason to use stack dynamic array. It's accepted as standard recently mainly for the compatibility of the latest C language standard C11. Since C has no vector, so C has motivation for it, and it's accepted as C11.

Comment: @user534498 Visual-C++ 2013 doesn't allow it, and it's supposed to be near-compliant to C11.  I guess that's one of the things it's missing.  EDIT: C11

Answer (score 1):

Such functionality was suggested ([N3639 - Runtime-sized arrays with automatic storage duration](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html)) on 4/2013 and  was accepted.

It is now part of the [C++ 2013-05-15 Committee Draft](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf)

From 8.3.4:

```
void f(unsigned int n)
{
    int a[n]; // type of a is “array of runtime bound of int”
}
```